# Does SoftDeleteColumnDeletionDetectionPolicy still keep data in Azure Search?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

This is mostly a GDPR question.

When data is soft-deleted using Azure Search's `SoftDeleteColumnDeletionDetectionPolicy`, is all of the original document data still kept, or is only enough info (document ID and the `IsDeleted` bit) kept to know that the document has been deleted?

Looking around at the Azure documentation, this isn't clear. It's clear that this is intended to use for soft deletes on the data source side, but it's not clear whether Azure also treats this strictly as a soft-delete, and therefore keeps all the data and just marks the document as deleted via the soft-delete bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an Azure Search indexer processes a document marked as deleted, the document is removed from the search index (i.e., "hard" deleted).

Comment: Yay, one less thing we have to deal with re: GDPR!